# Update multiple rows with Django (different ids) using different values for each id (as keys)

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model:

I have some items:

```
grocery = {
   status : True,
   fruits: ['1', '23', '55'],
   comments: {'1': "test", '23': "test2", '55': ""}
```

I have a rough potential Django update query:

```
Fruit.objects.all().filter(id__in=grocery.get('fruits')).update(status=grocery.get('status'), comment=grocery.get('comments'))
```

I'm successfully updating the status but I want to dynamically update the comments so that if the Fruit object in question has, for example, `id: 23`, the fruit comment will be `test2`, or if the object has `'id: 55'` it will be `''`

Comment: If you expect to get one update query, you can't. Bulk update does the same thing on many instances, it cannot do different things. That's what for loops and instance modifications are for. Also, your payload is not very normalized, making things harder then they should be: you repeat the ID on both members, you can just make a fruits to include the comments (as a dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact syntax but i think of something like this:

```
for f in Fruit.objects.filter(id__in=grocery.get('fruits')) :
    f.update(status=grocery.get('status'), comment=grocery['comments'][f.id])
```